# Refactoring a huge function into a set of smaller functions

Tags: python, refactoring

In terms of clean code, how should a function that has nested for loops, if-else statements, and while loops be refactored? What would be the ideal, clean structure for a big function like this? Is it acceptable to break a function like this up to nested functions?

```py
def main():

try:
    for 
        if
            for 
                while 

                    for

        for
            if 
                for 

                    if 
                    else

                    if
                    else

                    if 

except:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only nest loops iniside loops if you really need, otherwise avoid nesting them (for algorithmic performance reasons).

Use the Omri answer advice to identify each step you are doing, give each step a clear name and extract the step into its own function (that you call to perform the step in the original function).

This is different from nesting functions, something done for different reasons.
You are just making calls to helper functions placed somewhere else (not nested in your function).

Do not surround everything in a try block, and avoid the catch all empty `except:`. Surround only around the specific (or the few statements) than can cause trouble, and be specific to list in the expect clause only the error or error category(ies) you are expecting there.

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly opinion-based and depends on the code itself. A good rule of thumb is that each function needs to have one logical purpose.